# values from 2 arrays to mysql table php

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Well please help to correct syntax fo the following code. I have to select 2 values from one table and insert them in another table. one value is taking from PHP variable.this all needs to be done using Opencart model file

```
    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "rate_cost SET rate_cost = " . $this->db->escape($data['rate_cost']) );        
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT competition_rate, customer_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer  WHERE competition_rate NOT LIKE 0";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
$rates = array();
$customer_ids = array();
foreach($query->row['competition_rate'] as $result){
    $rates[] = $result * $data['name'];
}
foreach($query->row['customer_id'] as $result2){
    $customer_ids[] = $result2;
}

$sums = $rates;
$ids = $customer_ids;;
$sql = ("INSERT INTO 'customer_transaction'(customer_id,amount) VALUES'".$ids.",".$sums"'");
    }
```

I am getting the folowing error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport\admin\model\competition\newsletter.php on line 18

Comment: You are missing the concatenation operator in the last part of your `$sql` definition. Change that to: `VALUES'".$ids.",".$sums."'");`.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors in your `$sql` query, the correct syntax for [**`INSERT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) query is

```
INSERT INTO table (columns) VALUES ('values');
```

So youre missing paranthesis for your values and you dind't surround correctly with quotes. So change as follow

```
VALUES ('".$ids."','".$sums"')");
```

So the complete query will look like that

```
("INSERT INTO 'customer_transaction'(customer_id,amount) VALUES ('".$ids."','".$sums"')");
```

Comment: Sorry now I am getting the following. 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"')"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sport\admin\model\competition\newsletter.php on line 18

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: This error doesn't come because of the query

Comment: I know, I just need help with that too. Sorry if enythin.

Comment: Try to change `WHERE competition_rate NOT LIKE 0";` to `WHERE competition_rate != 0";`